Order of action processing in Redux Listener Middleware
I'm trying to implement buffering using Redux Toolkit Listener Middleware.
I would like to buffer web socket messages until some entity is loaded using RTK Query. I discovered that some messages are skipped when using approach with listenerApi.fork and listenerApi.take.
I started with implementing listener that starts out after certain action and then adds new messages to an array. If API call is fulfilled it should consume the buffer and continue consuming new messages without buffering them.
startListening({
        actionCreator: startBuffer,
        effect: async (_, listenerApi) => {
            const buffer = [];
            let shouldBuffer = true;
            const task = listenerApi.fork(async () => {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        const [action] = await listenerApi.take(
                            isAnyOf(api.endpoints.getState.matchFulfilled, forwardMessage.match)
                        );
                        if (shouldBuffer) {
                            if (forwardMessage.match(action)) {
                                buffer.push(action.payload);
                            } else {
                                buffer.forEach((msg) => messageProcessor(msg, listenerApi));
                                shouldBuffer = false;
                            }
                        } else if (forwardMessage.match(action)) {
                            messageProcessor(action.payload, listenerApi);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            });

            await listenerApi.condition(stopBuffer.match);
            task.cancel();
        }

However I noticed in unit test that this approach is skipping some actions:
store.dispatch(forwardMessage({}));
store.dispatch(forwardMessage({}));

This would only process first message. To solve that I would need to add setTimeout in between:
store.dispatch(forwardMessage({}));
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1))
store.dispatch(forwardMessage({}));

Another approach that I had in mind was to spawn new listener on each forwardMessage and then make it wait using listenerApi.condition and process the message once the condition is met (action received or state has loaded entity). I'm not sure though if this will keep the order of incoming messages.
I also have a similar problem with the other way around - sending messages. Using the listener.fork approach middleware would skip actions dispatched consecutively.
EDIT:
I think this is because take is a one time listener and it does not re-register in time for the next action. I'm wondering how this is solved in redux-saga.
I solved this by not dispatching any action on message event. Simply add message to an array and have a fork effect that has a while(true) loop in which you consume the buffer or wait using delay for some milliseconds.
listenerApi.fork(async () => {                   
                    while (true) {
                        await listenerApi.condition(startBuffer.match);
                        const processMessagesTask = listenerApi.fork(async (forkApi) => {
                            await listenerApi.condition(api.endpoints.getState.matchFulfilled);
                           
                            while (true) {
                                if (buffer.length > 0) {
                                    const toProcess = buffer.shift();
                                    if (toProcess) {
                                        messageProcessor(toProcess, listenerApi);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    await forkApi.delay(50);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        await listenerApi.condition(endBuffer.match);
                        processMessagesTask.cancel();
                    }
                });

